# regular expression that matches any word that starts with pre and ends in al

Tags: regex, perl

The following regular expression gives me proper results when tried in Notepad++ editor but when tried with the below perl program I get wrong results. Right answer and explanation please.

The link to file I used for testing my pattern is as follows:

(http://sainikhil.me/stackoverflow/dictionaryWords.txt)

Regular expression: ^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$

Perl program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_matches {
    my $pattern = "^Pre(.*)al(\s*)\$";
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fp, $file;

    while(my $line = <$fp>) {
        if($line =~ m/$pattern/) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
}

print_matches @ARGV;
```

Comment: don't escape the dollar sign

Comment: Are you sure? I get the following error if I do that.

Final $ should be \$ or $name at ex2.pl line 8, within string
syntax error at ex2.pl line 8, near "= "^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$""

Comment: Actually, the OP is right on this one.  The `$` needs to be escaped because it's in a double-quoted string rather than a regex pattern.  `"^Pre(.*)al(\s*)\$"` (needs escaping) vs. `/^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$/` (don't escape). Incidentally, if you want to assign the pattern to a variable as a regular string, you don't need to escape the `$` if you use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it completely changed the problem, so none of the answers made sense any more. Editing your question is fine, but please make sure you don't invalidate existing answers when you do so. Also, `$foo = m/bar/;` doesn't do what you think it does; you meant `$foo = qr/bar/;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting messed up by assigning the pattern to a variable before using it as a regex and putting it in a double-quoted string when you do so.

This is why you need to escape the `$`, because, in a double-quoted string, a bare `$` indicates that you want to interpolate the value of a variable. (e.g., `my $str = "foo$bar";`)

The reason this is causing you a problem is because the backslash in `\s` is treated as escaping the `s` - which gives you just plain `s`:

```
$ perl -E 'say "^Pre(.*)al(\s*)\$";'
^Pre(.*)al(s*)$
```

As a result, when you go to execute the regex, it's looking for zero or more `s`es rather than zero or more whitespace characters.

The most direct fix for this would be to escape the backslash:

```
$ perl -E 'say "^Pre(.*)al(\\s*)\$";'
^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$
```

A better fix would be to use single quotes instead of double quotes and don't escape the `$`:

```
$ perl -E "say '^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$';"
^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$
```

The best fix would be to use the `qr` (quote regex) operator instead of single or double quotes, although that makes it a little less human-readable if you print it out later to verify the content of the regex (which I assume to be why you're putting it into a variable in the first place):

```
$ perl -E "say qr/^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$/;"
(?^u:^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$)
```

Or, of course, just don't put it into a variable at all and do your matching with

```
if($line =~ m/^Pre(.*)al(\s*)$/) ...
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for sharing knowledge. After looking at your explanation, I recently edited my program. That shows me all lines instead of matching. Any reason why?

Comment: @saint1729 - It looks like my last two fixes confused you. If you're assigning the pattern to a variable, it should be `my $pattern = qr/^Pre.*al\s*$/;`, not `m/.../`. With `m/.../`, it's trying to match against the content of `$_`, getting no matches, and assigning `undef` to `$pattern`, which then matches everything. Changing `m/.../` to `qr/.../` gives me correct-looking results (Prebendal, Predial, Prejudicial, Preternatural as the only matches).

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

- You should not escape the dollar sign
- The capturing group around the whitespaces is useless
- Same for the capturing group around the dot `.`

which leads to:

```
^Pre.*al\s*$
```

If you don't want words like `precious final` to match (because of the middle whitespace, change regex to:

```
^Pre\S*al\s*$
```

Included in your code:

```
while(my $line = <$fp>) {
        if($line =~ /^Pre\S*al\s*$/m) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing trailing newline character(s):

```
    while(my $line = <$fp>) {
        $line =~ s/[\r\n]+$//s;
```

And, to match only *words* that begin with `Pre` and end with `al`, try this regular expression:

```
/^Pre\w*al$/
```

(`\w` means any letter of a word, not just any character)

And, if you want to match both `Pre` and `pre`, do a case-insensitive match:

```
/^Pre\w*al$/i
```